# Why does the logarithm algorithm for Divide Two Integers fail some special test cases?

Tags: java, math

I tried to used the formula `a/b = e^(ln a - ln b)` to solve the infamous `Divide 2 Integers` without using / % * question, however for some test cases `(dividend=Integer.MAX_VALUE or MIN_VALUE and divisor=1)` my solution fails.

Why does it fail?

[EDIT]: The answers I get for that test case are `(MAX-1 or MIN+1)`. I'd like to know why this happens.

```
public int divide(int dividend, int divisor) {
    boolean neg = false;
    if ((dividend < 0 && divisor > 0) || (dividend > 0 && divisor < 0))
        neg = true;

    long a = dividend;
    a = Math.abs(a);
    long b = divisor;
    b = Math.abs(b);

    double res = Math.pow(Math.E, Math.log(a) - Math.log(b));
    int ans = Math.floor(res);
    return neg ? -ans : ans;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails'. It is clear that the result would not be exact the same as using `/`.

Comment: @JonathanM [the homework tag is deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100).

Comment: I found this on an online judge, it is now clear where all my homework questions come from.

Comment: @MrSmith42, I've expanded my question.

Answer (score 4):

The root of the problem here is in **intermediate** results of calculations.

Double is a **floating-point type**, when you use it, you **may loose precision**.

You use double in your intermediate calculations:

```
double res = Math.pow(Math.E, Math.log(a) - Math.log(b));
int ans = Math.floor(res);
```

For example if you use 5 and 1, res = 4.999999999999, Math.floor(res) will return 4.

With Integer.MAX_VALUE you have 2147483647 (original value), but the result is 2147483646. The reason is exactly the same as for 5.

Comment: Solution: use rounding rather than `floor`.

Comment: You can't use rounding. Because the quotient might go over.

Comment: Better change the return type to double, to correctly display the nature of calculations.

Comment: Right, rounding may fail too.

Comment: Does this kind of precision loss only occur when divisor=1? When the computer calculates e^(ln N)?

Comment: No, loss of precision (with float-pointign types) occurs always (= often and unexpected). Try System.out.println(0.2 + 0.1); you will be surprised.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23024/discussion-between-alex-kreutznaer-and-some-noob-student)